# Avoiding react component rerenders on all state changes

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns, react-hooks, gatsby

My `<App />` component has 2 pieces of state. The first piece of state updates on user interaction and then triggers an update in the second piece of state using the `useEffect()` hook. This causes 2 re-renders anytime that the user clicks on the button. Can someone help me figure out how to only rerender `<App />` after the second piece of state updates? Is this a bad react pattern?

Here is the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wispy-butterfly-nm5fsr

You can view the console to see the re-renders.

The reason I need to fix this is because I have a real project where re-renders are happening and very large props are being passed between components. The re-renders are causing visible lag. I would share the entire project, but it's way too much for a stack overflow question.

Comment: You want to avoid the double re-renders or prevent children from re-rendering?

Comment: I want to avoid the double rerender

Comment: Just remove the strict mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's rendering twice because you're updating state once per render, instead of updating both states at the same time.  Consider what you're doing here:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  if (state1) setState1((prev) => prev + 1);
  else setState1(1);
};

useEffect(() => {
  if (state1) setState2(state1 + 10);
}, [state1]);
```

This basically means:

> Update `state1` and re-render.  On that next render, update `state2` and re-render.

The calculation to derive the state updates isn't terribly complicated.  Add `1` to a number, and add `10` to a number.  You don't need to wait for the component to re-render to know what `state1` will be.  It will be the current value *plus 1*, which is easily calculated.  You can use that calculation to update both states:

```
const handleClick = () => {
  if (state1) {
    const newState1 = state1 + 1;
    setState1(newState1);
    setState2(newState1 + 10);
  } else {
    setState1(1);
    setState2(10);
  }
};
```

---

Or, *even better*, you don't need two state values in the first place.  In this example, `state2` is *derived from* `state1` (and doing so is not a difficult or expensive calculation).  Which means you're *duplicating* state.

Don't duplicate state.  Just derive the second value from `state1`:

```
const [state1, setState1] = useState(null);

const handleClick = () => {
  if (state1) setState1((prev) => prev + 1);
  else setState1(1);
};

return (
  <div className="App">
    {console.log("Rerendering children...")}
    <Child1 state1={state1} />
    <Child2 state2={state1 ? state1 + 10 : null} />

    <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
      Change State 1!
    </button>
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the useEffect hook is correctly set up to update state2 when state1 changes. However, since you have two separate state updates in the handleClick function, it will trigger a re-render after both updates. If you want to avoid re-rendering after the first state update and only re-render after the second state update, you can use a combination of the useState and useEffect hooks. Here's how you can achieve that:

```
const handleClick = () => {
    if (state1) {
      const newState1 = state1 + 1;
      setState1(newState1);
    } else {
      setState1(1);
    }
  };
```

I have removed the setState2 call from the handleClick function, so it only updates state1 when the button is clicked.

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (state1) {
      setState2(state1 + 10);
    }
  }, [state1]);

  // Add a second useEffect to handle state2 changes
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state2 !== null) {
      // Now you can perform actions when state2 changes
      console.log("State2 updated:", state2);
    }
  }, [state2]);
```

I have added a second useEffect hook to watch for changes in state2. This will allow you to perform actions when state2 changes, and it won't cause a re-render of the component when state1 changes.

Now, your component will re-render only when state1 changes, and you can handle state2 changes separately in the second useEffect.